# Regex for Guest VS Registered User Funnel in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

**How should I setup a guest checkout conversion funnel?**

I need to setup a guest vs registered user funnel to track conversions separately. Specifically, we need to look at goal completions (conversions), cart abandonment, bounce, exit, as we A/B different page views (changing UI on middle pages).

> Problems:

- > 1) The regex does not seem to work for the guest funnel visualization. Google reports 0 sessions in the visualization funnel, although it shows that 0.8% of visits completed this goal.
- > 2) Ideally, I'd like to NOT tag each guest page with the query string parameter.

The typical flow goes: Cart > Login > Shipping > Delivery > Payment > Review > Complete

I begin at Shipping because that is where the fork occurs for a guest (where we add on the querystring parameter).

**Guest Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: ^\/complete\?guest=.*$


 Step 1: /shipping?guest=1 (REQUIRED)
 Step 2: /delivery
 Step 3: /payment
 Step 4: /review
 Step 5: /complete?guest=1 (Destination)
```

**Registered User Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: ^/complete$

 Step 1: /shipping (REQUIRED)
 Step 2: /delivery
 Step 3: /payment
 Step 4: /review
 Step 5: /complete (Destination)
```

The registered user goal regex is working thanks to Allen, but the *guest goal* is still not working as desired.

I have tried these regex:

```
 ^\/complete\?guest=.*$
 \/complete\?guest=.*$
 /complete\?guest=.*$
 /complete\?guest=1
 /complete/?guest=1
```

Google says, **This Goal was completed in 0 sessions**

Yet it shows a destination conversion rate of 0.8% for the goal. My understanding is that this happens because Google only evaluates the last URL, which is a match. However for the session conversions, the regex must apply to all pages in the funnel for the visualization to list the session number.

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete working example if anyone finds it helpful. The trick was that the steps also needed regex syntax and to take the final destination out of the steps.

**Guest Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: /complete\?guest=1$

 Step 1: /shipping\?guest=1 (REQUIRED)
 Step 2: /delivery
 Step 3: /payment
 Step 4: /review
```

**Registered User Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: ^/complete$

 Step 1: /shipping (REQUIRED)
 Step 2: /delivery
 Step 3: /payment
 Step 4: /review
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need a regex for guests, and another for registered users. If that's the case, maybe you could use:

Guests:

```
/complete\?guest=1$
```

Registered users:

```
^/complete$
```

If you want a single regex for both guests and registered users, maybe:

```
\/(complete|shipping)
```

Please, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Not sure. If I understand correctly, it would evaluate the regex for the destination of the complete page only. That is the source of my confusion. If the regex applies to only the destination page, but needs to also apply to the steps of the funnel, how it could ever work. 1.8% seems too high, like it is combining the two pages (shipping and complete) as a destination goal. I still think the clue has to do with the required for the first step, and what to make of that.

Comment: I just had a look into the Google Analytics funnelling. Do you think the problem may be caused due to the fact that you set the type as "Regular Expressions", but on the steps you use plain urls? Could you try to escape the question marks on the steps, such as: `/shipping\?guest=1` and `/complete\?guest=1` to see if it helps? Thanks!

Comment: I think my mistake is that I am including the destination in the funnel, which I should not.

Answer (score 2):

How about sending virtual page hits? will be great if you have separate templates for each page and send virtual hits.

Comment: How would that display in the Goal Funnel or the Funnel Visualization? They want to keep the visual tools.

Comment: It is the same page, but I could have the .Net MVC code write javascript to the view to make the virtual page view call.

Comment: You can probably setup - virtual page view based on if-else rule. Here is a sample code for SHIPPING page http://pastebin.com/j7QdFnyS  for guest urls you can append guest in the beginning. But CART page and Login in  funnels will have all visits from both guest and registered user.

Comment: I don't think virtual page views are the way to go because that adds complexity the funnel. There has got to be a way to use some sort of regex to get it to recognize the querystring parameters.

Comment: Ok. if you have guest parameters in all pages after LOGIN, Regex should work.

Comment: To separate guest vs registered, wouldn't I also have to have a param for the registered checkout too? Otherwise, the registered funnel would ignore the query string and pick up the guests too, no? If there were 10 orders, I would want to see 6 guests and 4 registered users in their separate goals.

Comment: You can set regex for both goals, something like - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J-NrzsXkTn3AzRzPKpEiR5v0Xn7Ev8fmUh_OczyNbVw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can do that, but 1) can the param start on Step 3 as you have it? Doesn't the funnel have to start at the required first step, which would be /shipping? I'd rather that it didn't have to, but I thought I read only the first and last step is evaluated by the regex. I will give this a try and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. There were 50 some conversions but it shows 0 in the funnel for both. I used ^\/complete\?guest=.*$ and \/complete$ for the regex

Comment: What if I set the guest regex to ^\/.*\?.*(guest).*     Does the regex in the goal have to contain the destination URL as the pattern or does it operate like a regular regex where the entire regex pattern must match each step or the first and last step?

Comment: Goal complete regex I gave is working see - https://regex101.com/r/UIB66Y/1  Feels like something wrong with your questions.  (you can also test new goal config. by click "Re-verify" ). Sorry

Comment: The registered user regex is working, but the guest is still not returning any numbers in the funnel. It is showing conversion rate, but nothing in the funnel itself. I am trying this expression now: \/\w+\?ig=.*$

Comment: I found what I believe to be the source of the problem. The required attribute of step 1 is causing the sessions not to record. How can we tweak the regex so that step 1 is also recorded in the funnel?